# multiple buttons in FORM

Tags: php, html

**productdetail.php**

```
    <form method="post" action="cart.php">
    --data is to kept in session --
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" /> 
    <button  class="">ADD TO CART</button>
    <button  class="">BUY NOW</button>
    </from>
```

ONCLICK **ADD TO CART** it should redirect to

```
 --> cart.php --> productdetail.php
```

ONCLICK **BUY NOW** it should redirect to

```
-->cart.php-->purchasing page(viewcart.php)
```

**how should i process them in cart.php**

FOR ADD TO CART : it should go to cart.php and then productdetail.php
FOR BUY NOW : cart.php->viewcart.php

Comment: what actually is your question???cant understand..

Comment: it is shopping cart website 
on productdetail.php we have two buttons
"add to cart" and "buy now"
cart(name,price,qty) is processed in cart.php
on click : ADD to cart = --> cart.php --> productdetail.php
on click : BUY NOW = -->cart.php-->purchasing page(viewcart.php)
how can i handle these two actions and redirect to page based on button clicked

Comment: you can add any number of buttons in an HTML form but can have only one submit button..Here you dont have any submit button..

Comment: That's STILL not a question.

Comment: @Lal, a form may contain any number of submit buttons, and a `button` element as in the question creates one. Recognizing which button was used is a different issue. But we don’t really know what the issue is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle the redirection on cart.php. And to know which was clicked, you can do a JS to fill a hidden input based on your button being clicked:

```
<form method="post" action="cart.php" id="someFormId"> <!-- I added id to form -->
    <!-- your other form inputs and etc here -->


    <!-- I added a new input hidden  -->
    <input type="hidden" name="userAction" id="inputUserAction" value="" /> 

    <!-- I added type, class and data to both buttons  -->
    <button class="formButton" data-user-action="add" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
    <button class="formButton" data-user-action="buy" type="button">BUY NOW</button>
</form>
```

Considering you are using jQuery, add a click listener:

```
$(function(){ //this is shorthand for document.ready
    $('.formButton').on('click',function(){
        $('#inputUserAction').val($(this).data('userAction')); //update our hidden with the data
        $('#someFormId').submit(); //submit the form
    });
});
```

Now you will receive `$_POST['userAction']` on your `cart.php` which you can do your ifs based on 'add' or 'buy' and redirect to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form method="post" action="cart.php" id="someFormId"> <!-- I added id to form -->
    <!-- your other form inputs and etc here -->


    <!-- I added a new input hidden  -->
    <input type="hidden" name="userAction" id="inputUserAction" value="" /> 

    <!-- I added type, class and data to both buttons  -->
    <button class="formButton" data-user-action="add" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
    <button class="formButton" data-user-action="buy" type="button">BUY NOW</button>
</form>

$(function(){ //this is shorthand for document.ready
    $('.formButton').on('click',function(){
        $('#inputUserAction').val($(this).data('userAction')); //update our hidden with the data
        $('#someFormId').submit(); //submit the form
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want ?

```
<form method="post" action="cart.php">
    --data is to kept in session --
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" /> 
    <button  class="cartbutton">ADD TO CART</button>
    <button  class="buynowbutton">Buy Now</button>
</from>
```

Comment: how should i process them in cart.php
FOR ADD TO CART : it should go to cart.php and then productdetail.php
FOR BUY NOW : cart.php--->viewcart.php

Comment: cart.php is handling all the data like name,price,qty and storing in session . on click buy now it should go to cart.php and then viewcart.php

Comment: so change the onclick event link location `onclick="location.herf='./cart.php'"`

Comment: then it will go to cart.php
now cart.php has two tasks .
on click  BUY NOW :after processing redirect to viewcart.php,
on click ADD TO CART : after processing redirect to productdetail.php.
how can i do this?

Comment: pass arguments to `cart.php` `./cart.php?act=buy_now` then at the top of `cart.php`, check for act and do what's needed and redirect